# How to get Google Analytics API Data from Account without User Management Rights

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, service-accounts

On my Google Analytics account, I have reading/editing access to multiple other accounts - e.g., I can see all their data on the OAuth 2.0 Playground.

Now, I want to access this same data via OAuth with a Service Account - I want to have a script that extracts it every day for me, instead of doing it manually. However, this requires me to add the Service Account's generated email address to all the Google Analytics accounts that I wish to pass the reading/editing rights onto.

The problem is, I don't have user management rights on all those accounts. Even though I can see their data, I can't add another user to them.

Is there any way to pass on my own (main) account as a service account or any similar method to get the data despite lacking user management rights?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... I simply want to get the data that I already have access to, but automatically instead of manually. What's so absurd about it?

Comment: "Absurd" is the part where you ask if you can circumvent the permission system. For the rest of it you can run a schedule on a Google spreadsheet with the Google Analytics add-on (which runs with your usual account, so it will have access to all the GA accounts that you have access to).

Comment: I didn't mean to per se circumvent it, I just thought that one might be able to use the main account to get that data - For example in a way like the one you just described - if that's what you mean by circumventing. I'll try out the spreadsheets, thanks!